# How to eager load relations for single eloquent object?

Tags: json, rest, laravel, eloquent

I have this `Comment` model with belongs to relationship.

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

While in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $comment = $this->dispatch(
        new StoreCommentCommand($request->body, Auth::user()->id, $request->post_id)
    );

    return $comment;
}
```

When I return the `$comment` I also want nested user object, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `with()` on Builder object, whereas currently you are using on eloquent object. This will be your working code.

```
    return Comment::with('user')->where('id', $comment->id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just eager load it...

```
return $comment->with('user');
```

Comment: Firstly it should be `return $comment->with('user')->get();`. Secondly I tried that, it returns all the comments in the db with user objects, I need only one :(

Comment: Have you verified that the `$comment` returned from the `StoreCommentCommand` class is a `Comment`?  `with()` should only be attaching users to the comments you already have.

Comment: It is an eloquent object. I did `$comment->save()` and then `return $comment`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, you can just assign the user to the comment before returning it.

```
$comment->user = Auth::user()
return $comment
```

The `with` eager-loading function isn't needed here.